# how can I change frame src using Greasemonkey?

Tags: greasemonkey

I visit a page and displays it to me on such a frame

```
<iframe src="link" id="pgl" class="surfer_frame" frameborder = "0" onload="showadbar('')"></iframe>
```

I would like to change the src for a text or another src using Greasemonkey. Anyone knows a way?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly. It's too simple.

Just set the *src* attribute of the *<iframe>* element to another URL.

> change the src for a text or another src

If you want to directly set the content to some text, use *srcdoc* attribute instead. *srcdoc* is handled with higher priority over *src*. You may want to remove the srcdoc attribute in order to subsequently reset the content to some URL source.

To get a reference to the *<iframe>* element you can use some *document* methods such as getElementById, querySelector (CSS selectors), evaluate (XPath expressions), aso.

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
var
  btn,
  ifr = document.querySelector('.surfer_frame')      // get element reference by class name
;

btn = document.createElement('button');              // generate a test button
btn.innerHTML = 'example.com';
btn.addEventListener('click', function()
{ ifr.removeAttribute('srcdoc');                     // remove attribute of higher priority
  ifr.setAttribute('src', 'http://example.com');     // set the new content URL
});
document.body.appendChild(btn);

btn = document.createElement('button');
btn.innerHTML = 'text';
btn.addEventListener('click', function()
{ // directly set some content
  ifr.setAttribute('srcdoc', '<html><body>Here is some content.</body></html>');
});
document.body.appendChild(btn);
```